# matebook x pro with ubuntu 20.04 also 22.04 can not resume from suspend or hibernation

Tags: suspend

My huawei matebook x pro which have intel I7 cpu and Intel® Iris® Xe GPU, can not resume from suspend (to ram) nor from hibernation (to disk) in most case. But occationally it could resume ok from suspend and hiberation.
I check the dmesg, it seems the system is hung at somewhere just after 's2idle' in failed case, which before the system really hiberation or suspend.
And the system could resume once the following message is recorded just after 's2idle';

Here is the dmesg log with grep.

================================
success case :

```
Apr 24 02:09:06.667002 TianFu kernel: input input9: Unknown key pressed, code: 0x02c1  
Apr 24 02:09:10.322934 TianFu kernel: input input9: Unknown key pressed, code: 0x02c1  
Apr 24 02:09:17.094901 TianFu kernel: input input9: Unknown key pressed, code: 0x02c1  
Apr 24 02:09:18.643035 TianFu kernel: input input9: Unknown key pressed, code: 0x02c1  
Apr 24 02:09:26.210856 TianFu kernel: wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 70:8c:b6:54:a3:f0 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)  
Apr 24 02:09:26.450879 TianFu kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)  
Apr 24 02:09:26.454840 TianFu kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.003 seconds  
Apr 24 02:09:46.123431 TianFu kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Timed out waiting for suspend events  
Apr 24 02:09:46.123577 TianFu kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Suspend timeout bit: 6  
Apr 24 02:09:46.123590 TianFu kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Suspend notifier action (3) failed: -110  
Apr 24 02:09:46.123601 TianFu kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.  
Apr 24 02:09:46.123612 TianFu kernel: OOM killer disabled.  
Apr 24 02:09:46.123625 TianFu kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.  
Apr 24 02:09:46.123633 TianFu kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)  
Apr 24 02:09:46.123643 TianFu kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked  
Apr 24 02:09:46.123654 TianFu kernel: input input9: Unknown key pressed, code: 0x02c1  
Apr 24 02:09:46.123858 TianFu kernel: input input9: Unknown key pressed, code: 0x02c1  
Apr 24 02:09:46.123936 TianFu kernel: input input9: Unknown key pressed, code: 0x02c1  
Apr 24 02:09:46.124008 TianFu kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked  
Apr 24 02:09:46.124020 TianFu kernel: input input9: Unknown key pressed, code: 0x02c1  
Apr 24 02:09:46.124090 TianFu kernel: nvme nvme0: 8/0/0 default/read/poll queues
```

================================
failed case:

```
Apr 24 02:09:50.149751 TianFu kernel: wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 70:8c:b6:54:a3:ec (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=60)  
Apr 24 02:09:50.165739 TianFu kernel: wlp0s20f3: associated  
Apr 24 02:09:50.197742 TianFu kernel: input input9: Unknown key pressed, code: 0x02c1  
Apr 24 02:09:50.238849 TianFu kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp0s20f3: link becomes ready  
Apr 24 02:09:50.957731 TianFu kernel: wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 70:8c:b6:54:a3:ec by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)  
Apr 24 02:09:51.213744 TianFu kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)  
-- Boot db9fe738ec984e0990cb7cea26938157 --  
Apr 24 02:12:56.553262 TianFu kernel: Linux version 5.15.0-27-generic (buildd@ubuntu) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #28-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 14 04:55:28 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 5.15.0-27.28-generic 5.15.30)  
Apr 24 02:12:56.553280 TianFu kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-27-generic root=UUID=dd4bdf2f-a3de-45de-92e5-f95de1cd64b8 ro resume=UUID=321d3cde-38ec-4263-b273-a658fef4af67 quiet splash i915.enable_psr=0 vga=0 vt.handoff=7  
Apr 24 02:12:56.553289 TianFu kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:  
Apr 24 02:12:56.553294 TianFu kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel  
Apr 24 02:12:56.553299 TianFu kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD  
Apr 24 02:12:56.553304 TianFu kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine  
Apr 24 02:12:56.553310 TianFu kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls  
Apr 24 02:12:56.553313 TianFu kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai    
Apr 24 02:12:56.553318 TianFu kernel: x86/split lock detection: #AC: crashing the kernel on kernel split_locks and warning on user-space split_locks  
Apr 24 02:12:56.553321 TianFu kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'  
Apr 24 02:12:56.553325 TianFu kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'  
Apr 24 02:12:56.553330 TianFu kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'  
Apr 24 02:12:56.553333 TianFu kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x020: 'AVX-512 opmask'  
Apr 24 02:12:56.553337 TianFu kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x040: 'AVX-512 Hi256'
```

Comment: > nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0  I add this in /etc/default/grub to disable nvme to power saving, it seems the problem fixed up. Maybe it is because that the nvme has entered power saving state before rest filesys sync the data to nvme.

Comment: It looks promising indeed. If you test it successfully you can answer your own question.

Comment: did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Liquorix Kernel. It will probably work.

> Liquorix is a distro kernel replacement built using the best configuration and kernel sources for desktop, multimedia, and gaming workloads.

https://liquorix.net/

**Install**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:damentz/liquorix && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install linux-image-liquorix-amd64 linux-headers-liquorix-amd64
```

Comment: @ArturMeinild I improved my answer.